# ul items in flex container shift on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap 4 and font awesome icons.

I am trying to create a side navbar with animation. When ever I hover over a ul item. All of the items below it shift up, hiding underneath it the item that is being hovered.

How can I prevent this behavior?

```html
<style type="text/css">
        .sidenav .container {
            position: fixed;
            overflow-x: visible;
            max-width: 50px;
            top: 15%;
            max-height: 70%;
            justify-content: left;
            padding-left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .nav-item .btn {
            color: lightgray;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #343a40;
            border-bottom: #0c0c0c solid;
            border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
            transition: color 400ms, width 400ms;
        }

        .sidenav .btn:focus {
            box-shadow: none !important;
        }

        .nav-item:hover > .btn:hover {
            background-color: lightgray;
            color: #343a40;
            width: 75px;
            position: absolute;
        }
</style>
<div class="sidenav">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notebookModal"><i
                            class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-2x"></i></button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNoteModal"><i
                            class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent them from moving up, remove the `position: absolute` from the hovered class:

```
.nav-item > .btn:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: #343a40;
    width: 75px;
}
```

---

**EDIT TO ADD:**

Hovering over one button affects the width of the others, because the width was set to 100%. To fix this, change the non-hover buttons to a value other than 100% (because the other non-hovered buttons become 100% wide which changes with the transition on hover).

You could choose the value, like `width: 55px;` for example, or calculate it based on the bootstrap `.btn` padding, which is a left padding of .75rem when I inspect the element. You gave the sidenav container a width of 50px and a left padding of 0, so you can use `calc()` to determine what 100% would be if the rem values change:

```
.nav-item > .btn {
  color: lightgray;
  width: calc(50px + .75rem);
  background-color: #343a40;
  border-bottom: #0c0c0c solid;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  transition: color 400ms, width 400ms;
}
```

Comment: This works but introduces another problem. When I hover over one button, all buttons in the `<ul>` changes width and color. How can I modify the selector so that only one `<li>` changes?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that now (there was a slight delay for the other button change so I didn't catch it right away). I have a few ideas in mind and will update my answer once I get a chance to test them to be sure!

Comment: I do not see the colors being affected, and with my latest edit to my answer they appear to work as expected. Let me know if you still see the colors on non-hovered buttons changing and I will look into it. Hope this has helped!

Answer (score -1):

you put the `:hover` selector on `.nav-item`, and not only on `.btn`. I think you need to change it to this:

```
.nav-item > .btn:hover {
        background-color: lightgray;
        color: #343a40;
        width: 75px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Comment: no dice the second button still hides underneath the first